# Changing the default tag for a project

Tags: support, retag-request

At Stack Overflow, Netty project is using [jboss-netty](/questions/tagged/jboss-netty) as its default tag.  However, JBoss / Red Hat asked us to remove the reference to JBoss / Red Hat names and thus we should not use `JBoss Netty` but use `Netty`.  To avoid any possible legal complication, I'd like to change the current default tag from [jboss-netty](/questions/tagged/jboss-netty) to [netty](/questions/tagged/netty).  How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

I doubt there can be any legal complications for the Netty project due to a third party's (Stack Overflow's) use of the name.  That said, a mod can merge [jboss-netty](/questions/tagged/jboss-netty) into [netty](/questions/tagged/netty) without making it a synonym, effectively deleting it.  One should see this at some point and hopefully do it :)

Comment: I wonder who should I contact to expedite this change.

Comment: This is the appropriate channel. I seriously don't think it needs to be expedited.

Comment: It was fast enough.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netty).

For those who are used to the previous status quo, I made [jboss-netty](/questions/tagged/jboss-netty) a synonym (although it might take a little time to finish sorting itself out).